# jquery mobile how focus to that item after filtering (searching) it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app for tizen tv samsung. it use jquery mobile 1.3.2 my goal is after typing in input and searching an item from listview first item in listview would be focused ( i use jquery.sidebar.min.js to show my listview in that dynamic panel) . please show the code in demo (like jsfidle)

```
 <input id='input' type='text'>

 <ol id="listUl" data-role="listview" data-icon="false"  style="margin-right: 5px;">
```

//dynamic list view

```
     document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
          $("#input").on('keyup', function(){
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $("#listUl li").each(function () {
           if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
               $(this).show();

               $("#listUl").focus();
               $(this).prev('.itemListClass').last().show();


           } else {
               $(this).hide();
           }
       });

   });
```

// here is how i dynamicly with json parsing add list of item

```
if (ind === 1)  {
        return "<li class=\"itemListClass\" id=\"movieListId\" data-theme=\"b\" style=\"padding-top:25px;padding-left: 15px;line-height:70px\"><a style=\"font-size:1.5em;\" class=\"list\"  href='" + entry.video_url + "'>" + entry.title[0] + "</a></li>";

    }else {

    return "<li class=\"itemListClass\" id=\"movieListId\" style=\"padding-left: 15px;margin-left: 10px;line-height:70px\"><a style=\"font-size:1.5em;\" class=\"list\"  href='" + entry.video_url + "'>" + entry.title[0] + "</a></li>";
    }
```

i have tried with $("#listUl").focus(); to focus the first item of listView after opening side panel without luck, i use this app on tv so no mouse or click only keyboard (by remote control). my second goal is after focusing the first item in the filtered listview , i can navigate (focusing) second and third and nth element by keyboard. please help me